# How to map a relation in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have 3 tables

```
=================    =================    =================
| TableA        |    | RelationAC    |    | TableC        |
=================    =================    =================
| IdA           |    | Id            |    | IdC           |
|               |    | IdA           |    |               |
| Field1A       |    | IdC           |    | Field1C       |
=================    =================    =================
```

And this are my model's code:

```
public partial class TableA
{
    public TableA()
    {
       this.RelationAC = new HashSet<RelationAC>();
    }

    [Key]
    public decimal IdA { get; set; }
    public string Field1A { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdA")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelationAC> RelationAC { get; set; }
}

public partial class TableC
{
    [Key]
    public decimal IdC { get; set; }
    public string Field1C { get; set; }
}


public partial class RelationAC    
{
    public RelationAC    ()
    {
        this.TableC= new HashSet<TableC>();
    }
    [Key]
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public decimal IdA{ get; set; }
    public decimal IdC{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdC")]
    public virtual ICollection<TableC> TableC { get; set; }
}
```

If made this query

```
var query = from d in db.TableA 
            select d;


foreach( TableA  ta in query.Tolist())
{
    foreach(RelationAC rac in ta.RelationAC.Tolist())
    {
        TableC tc = rac.TableC.First(); // It allways has count = 0 , even my db has data
    } 
}
```

Why TableC tc is allways empty ?

Comment: Is this pseudo code or cut and paste?  Shouldn't it be rac.TableC.First() ?

Comment: you are right it must be.

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled?  You may need to eager load your navigation properties:  from d in db.TableA.Include(u => u.RelationAC .TableC)

Comment: yes, lazy loading is enabled, I'm going to try it .

Comment: There is something wrong, `Can't convert lambda expression in string type, because isn't a delegate type` when modify my query as you suggest me

Comment: Are you using an older EF (not 5?)  try : db.TableA.Include("RelationAC.TableC")

Comment: Now this problema was solvd. but now it is asking me for a problem of multiplicity. end rol has 1 or 0..1 RelationAC_TableC_Target of relation db.RelationAC_TableC has multiplicity of 1 or 0..1. what it mean ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25324/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-mark-oreta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is probably having issues w/ lazy loading.  Try eager loading the collection:

```
db.TableA.Include("RelationAC.TableC")
```